# How to remove listener for DocumentSnapshot events (Google Cloud FireStore)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in Google Cloud FireStore.

The Document object has a function call [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference?authuser=0#onSnapshot) to attaches a listener for DocumentSnapshot events.

Is there a function to remove that listener (like offSnapshot)? If not how can I implement it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In case of the web and node.js SDK, calling `onSnapshot` returns a function that you need to save in a variable and call when you want to remove the listener.

```
var unsubscribe = db.collection("cities").onSnapshot(function (querySnaphot) {
  // do something with the data.
});


// Stop listening to changes
unsubscribe();
```

The other SDKs offer similar functionality.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener for reference.

Comment: what to do in ts angular?

Comment: do we need to do this in angular?