# How to remove listener from task?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I'm adding a listener to a task returned from a Firestore `get()` request:

```
myQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(Runnable::run) 
    { 
       /*does something*/ 
    }
```

I know I can scope the listener to an activity with a`ddOnSuccessListener(activity, ...)` which would remove the listener when the activity stops. But, to keep my code clean I need to remove the listener myself (when the rxJava observable that wraps the request is disposed of - using

```
emitter.setCancellable{ 
/*remove the listener here*/ 
}
```

).

How can I remove the listener from the task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove listener for DocumentSnapshot events (Google Cloud FireStore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642652/how-to-remove-listener-for-documentsnapshot-events-google-cloud-firestore)

Comment: @puni nope..............

Comment: to remove a listener thats how it should be done see this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Comment: @puni that's for realtime updates

Comment: @Hatward no its not. Its for firestore. Both the mention links are for firestore.

Comment: @puni yeah firestore realtime updates - look at the title lol

Comment: @puni mr spagetti over here

Comment: @TomGatward Did you manage to find any solution? I gotta say, as I learn more about Task API less and less flexible it looks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `Task` listener, try [adding a snapshot listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)') on the `Query` itself.

This method returns a `ListenerRegistration` object that has a `remove` method.

Comment: I guess i could add a snapshot listener and call remove on the ListenerRegistration after the first update as well as when it needs disposing. That seems dirty though and i'm confused as to why the same can't be done for a simple get request.