# How to stop Firestore `get` query on componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

okay so I'm fetching data from Firestore in componentDidMount but while it's fetching the data if I change the component I get error saying:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

In Firebase real time database we call `ref.off()` to stop query.

Wondering how to do it in Firestore

```
componentDidMount() {
  Users.get().then(({ docs }) => {
    const users = docs.map(user => user.data());
      this.setState({ users });
  });
}

componentWillUnmount(){

}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to abort an ongoing `get()` operation. For `onSnapshot()` you get back a subscription that you can call to unsubscribe, but `get` doesn't have that as far as I can see.

Comment: How could I unsub on `onSnapshot()` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642652/how-to-remove-listener-for-documentsnapshot-events-google-cloud-firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround if anybody is still looking for the answer:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted = true;

  Users.get().then(({ docs }) => {
    const users = docs.map(user => user.data());
      if(this.mounted) this.setState({ users });
  });
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  this.mounted = false;
}
```

`this.mounted` will be false when component is unmounted and setState will not work.

Comment: This doesn't really abort the needless fetch or save network bandwith, it just suppresses the `React` warning about a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

As `Get` is not a real-time method so there is no way to stop it on componentWillUnmont, it should not be getting called once your component is unmounted.