# Firestore unsubscribe to updates

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am following this [Google Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Vf1D-rUMwE) example on YouTube and getting real time updates successfully. However, I don't know how to unsubscribe to updates because it's not explained in the video. I read the documentation to create an unsubscribe() function but it doesn't work for me.

```js
 getRealtimeUpdates = function(document) {
  firestore.collection("collection_name")
   .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
   querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.exists) {
     const myData = doc.data();
     // DO SOMETHING
    }
   });
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `firestore.collection().onSnapshot()` function returns a unsubscribe function. Just call it and you should be guchi.

You can also find another example here: [How to remove listener for DocumentSnapshot events (Google Cloud FireStore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642652/how-to-remove-listener-for-documentsnapshot-events-google-cloud-firestore)

Here is a snippet I created that should work:

```js
let unsubscribe;

getRealtimeUpdates = function(document) {
  unsubscribe = firestore.collection("collection_name")
   .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
   querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.exists) {
     const myData = doc.data();
     // DO SOMETHING
    }
   });
  });
 }
  
  // unsubscribe:
  
  unsubscribe();
```

Path to the corresponding Firebase Documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onSnapshot

> Returns
>   An unsubscribe function that can be called to cancel the snapshot listener.

Comment: Luckily I found your answer. I was searching explicitly for a example where you want to unsubscribe a firestore listener which is running inside a function, and this was the key.

Comment: Glad it helped you :) @KubaguetteTheTestobun

Comment: Here is google firebase node.js example:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-listen-detach#firestore_listen_detach-nodejs

Comment: [@GeraltDieSocke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8502436/geraltdiesocke) What if I want to unsubscribe inside the callback function inside an `if`?