# Can not remove firestore listener inside a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My code sample looks like following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    specialfunction();//listener for chat operations
}, []); 
const specialfunction = async() => {
   var mylistener = firebase.firestore()...onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
   //do something with the docs retrieved
   });
   //my unlucky try to remove the listener after I leave the screen
   return () => {
        try{
            mylistener();
            console.log("LISTENER REMOVED")
        }catch(error){console.log(error)};
    }
};
```

Usually, if you want to remove a firestore listener, you just call the variable you attached it to, in my example 'mylistener()'.
Unluckily, my listener is not stopping. After I leave the screen and reenter it multiple times and receive a document, I notice that my listener fires multiple times.
I also can not stop it outside my 'specialfunction' because it is not a database listener where I just can call the ref again and stop it, its about a firestore listener here.

I also can not put the 'mylistener' outside of the 'specialfunction', it needs to stay inside.

Can you help me to stop the 'mylistener' after I leave the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this solution was another [post but under a different topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53158150/8880650).
Important to understand was that you need to predefine a variable and after that overwrite it with the firestore listener.
In this case you will be able to detach the listener in the return part of the 'useEffect'-Hook once you leave the screen, code looks like this now:

```
let mylistener;
useEffect(() => {
    specialfunction();//listener for chat operations
    return () => {
        try{
            mylistener(); //here you need to remove the listener
            console.log("LISTENER REMOVED")
        }catch(error){console.log(error)};
    }
}, []); 
const specialfunction = async() => {
   var mylistener = firebase.firestore()...onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
   //do something with the docs retrieved
   });
};
```

Also, 'specialfunction' doesnt need to be async but I do async calls inside this function, its up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly well-versed in `firebase` but if you wished to remove event listener when dealing with `useEffect` hook, the template should be as below

```js
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp)

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp)
}, [collapsed, handleKeyUp])
```

Notice that in your `useEffect` hook you need to `return` a function which remove event listener

Comment: thx for the additional information! May I ask what the "keyup" is about? Is that the keyword for a listener which checks if you leave the screen with the "goback"-button on android?

Comment: `keyup` is not relevant to your case, all I'm showing here is that, the important part is `return () => xxxx`